# Learning Shorshei Hashemos

Tags: minhag, jewish-books

Can anyone Learn [Shorshei Hashemos](https://mysefer.com/Shorshei-HaShemot---Rabbi-Moshe-Zacut---Ramaz__p-595.aspx)? Or is there a procedure one must go through before learning it? Does one have to be 40? Does he have to have grey hair? Does she have to know Tanach? Does he have to "know" Shas?

Comment: You can not understand it if you haven't the basics. As you cannot begin mathematics without background , in a fundamental textbook

Comment: Let's say one can understand it, although they aren't 20 and married, don't have their stomach filled with Talmud and Ramabam. Then, is it still fine to learn it? @kouty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91003/discussion-between-kouty-and-moshe).